# Looking to delete a folder from explorer via registry

Tags: powershell

I am looking to delete highlighted value from registry shown in [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POCnf.png), where 'standard user' is the user id from which system is logged in. I need power shell script so that I can deploy it in every machine of my organization from backend and this highlighted value gets deleted from every user's system profile.

Comment: What are the errors in your existing attempt?

Comment: Please provide your code, along with error and your expected result

See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are planning on doing this via GPO I would advise two steps:

1- Create the script file and add it to the Files preference on your GPMC

2- Create a one-time Scheduled Task and run the remote script.

This code should do what you want as long as you adapt the Path to your needs. It will get a list of the Values inside the Key you point it to and match it using the where-object.

```
(Get-Item -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts\Business1\Tenants\Intune Test').Property | Where-Object{$_ -match 'Test Sync - Documents'} | Remove-Item
```

Deployment is up to you, please assume this code can be improved and or adapted. This is just the core block you need to achieve what you asked.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the command but I was not able to execute it via powershell. After successful execution via powershell, I will push this via intune or via GPO but I am getting below error:

PS C:\Users\StandardUser> (Get-Item -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts\Business1\Tenants\Intune Test').Property | Where-Object{$_ -match 'Test Sync - Documents'} | Remove-Item
>>
>>
>>
>>
>> ^C

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the entire error? What PowerShell version are you running?

Comment: Powershell is not actually running, I am using the same command shared by you but I have tested in my test infra with other command...... Registry got deleted but folder still exist in Explorer. Deleting folder was my main objective.

Comment: @ArpitSinha So your actual goal is to remove a folder from every user in the computer? Why were you trying to do it through registry then? The command I sent you removes the key from the registry. What was the command that you tested on your end?

Comment: @VanTech: Really thanks for helping me. I am using this command for manually deleting folder. Command: del "C:\Users\*\ACL\ACL - Supers Team Folder". * Is the logged in user alias and "ACL - Supers Team Folder" is the folder I am looking to delete.